# EcomDev PHPUnit with magento CE 1.9.x

Tags: phpunit

Please, tell me, does EcomDev PHPUnit work with community edition?

Comment: try it and see.

Answer (score 7):

I've used this nifty little site called Google which gave me a link that told me "Yes"

https://github.com/EcomDev/EcomDev_PHPUnit